# Count line lengths in file using command line tools

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting

#### Problem

If I have a long file with lots of lines of varying lengths, how can I count the occurrences of each line length?

#### Example:

file.txt

```
this
is
a
sample
file
with
several
lines
of
varying
length
```

Running `count_line_lengths file.txt` would give:

```
Length Occurences
1      1
2      2
4      3
5      1
6      2
7      2
```

Ideas?

Comment: how do you know `length=1` is for which word? you should store the word too.

Comment: **Language:** Preferably using a clever shell command. I could easily do this in something like Ruby or Python, but that's no fun ;)

Comment: @Bill I don't really care about the word, only the line lengths, unless I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This

- counts the line lengths using `awk`, then
- sorts the (numeric) line lengths using `sort -n` and finally
- counts the unique line length values `uniq -c`.

```
$ awk '{print length}' input.txt | sort -n | uniq -c
      1 1
      2 2
      3 4
      1 5
      2 6
      2 7
```

In the output, the first column is the number of lines with the given length, and the second column is the line length.

Comment: Or shorter: `awk '{print length}' input.txt | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Nice pipe snake, but counting and `uniq` could be done inside `awk` easily. I suppose sort also can be done in `gawk`. I prefer the pure `bash` solution.

Comment: I did this but we have *really* long lines and sort doesn't sort numbers correctly by default (I got output like `1 9575
   1 999` with this. To correctly sort numbers use `sort -g`, making the original `awk '{print length}' input.txt | sort -g | uniq -c`

Comment: @user82116 I believe replacing that `sort` command with `LC_ALL=C sort` would have the advantages of sorting characters properly too, as well as being faster.

Answer (score 32):

Pure awk

```
awk '{++a[length()]} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file.txt

4 3
5 1
6 2
7 2
1 1
2 2
```

Answer (score 13):

Using `bash` arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    ((histogram[${#line}]++))
done < file.txt

echo "Length Occurrence"
for length in "${!histogram[@]}"; do
    printf "%-6s %s\n" "${length}" "${histogram[$length]}"
done
```

Example run:

```
$ ./t.sh
Length Occurrence
1      1
2      2
4      3
5      1
6      2
7      2
```

Comment: @fedorqui It's not really portable though, so depending on the use case `awk` wins ;-) Just posted it because the OP specifically asked for something not involving another external language, which kind of also means `awk` (that's how I read it). On the upside, it's not even so much longer if you consider `while read l;do((h[${#l}]++));done<file.txt;for l in "${!h[@]}";do echo "$l ${h[$l]}";done` ...

Answer (score 9):

```
$ perl -lne '$c{length($_)}++ }{ print qq($_ $c{$_}) for (keys %c);' file.txt
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/56PU4r)

```
6 2
1 1
4 3
7 2
2 2
5 1
```

Comment: for golfing fun: `perl -lnE '$c{+length}++}{say "$_ $c{$_}" for keys %c'`

Comment: I had a file with a pathologically long line (700-1000MB) and of all the one-liners here, only this one didn't crash. +1!

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using basic unix utilities only:

```bash
$ printf "%s %s\n" $(for line in $(cat file.txt); do printf $line | wc -c; done | sort -n | uniq -c | sed -E "s/([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)/\2 \1/")
1 1
2 2
4 3
5 1
6 2
7 2
```

#### How it works?

1. Here's the source file:

   ```
   $ cat file.txt
   this
   is
   a
   sample
   file
   with
   several
   lines
   of
   varying
   length
   ```

   Replace each line of the source file with its length:

   ```
   $ for line in $(cat file.txt); do printf $line | wc -c; done
   4
   2
   1
   6
   4
   4
   7
   5
   2
   7
   6
   ```

   Sort and count the number of length occurrences:

   ```
   $ for line in $(cat file.txt); do printf $line | wc -c; done | sort -n | uniq -c
         1 1
         2 2
         3 4
         1 5
         2 6
         2 7
   ```

   Swap and format the numbers:

   ```
   $ printf "%s %s\n" $(for line in $(cat file.txt); do printf $line | wc -c; done | sort -n | uniq -c | sed -E "s/([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)/\2 \1/") 
   1 1
   2 2
   4 3
   5 1
   6 2
   7 2
   ```

Comment: `wc -c` counts the **bytes**, not the characters. If you have multibyte characters, you'll get larger numbers. Try  `echo -n "你好" | wc -c` vs. ` echo -n "你好" | wc -m`.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster You must be right, should I just replace `wc -c` with `wc -m` ?

Comment: I think it will be clear now for anyone reading your answer, it's enough to refer to the comment above.

Comment: Beware that lines with white space are split, and any occurrence of `%` in _file.txt_ will cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow for the columns to be swapped and don't need the headers, something as easy as

`while read line; do echo -n "$line" | wc -m; done < file | sort | uniq -c`

(without any advanced tricks with `sed` or `awk`) will work. The output is:

```
1 1
2 2
3 4
1 5
2 6
2 7
```

One important thing to keep in mind: `wc -c` counts the bytes, not the characters, and will not give the correct length for strings containing multibyte characters. Therefore the use of `wc -m`.

References:

[man uniq(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html)

[man sort(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)

[man wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html)

Comment: This does not count trailing spaces. $line needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '{print length}' FILENAME
```

Or next if you want the longest length:

```
awk '{ln=length} ln>max{max=ln} END {print FILENAME " " max}'
```

You can combine above command with find using -exec option.